# Bootstrap 3 Collapse Glitch

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Site in question: http://www.cqwebdesign.co.uk/wine-site/france.html

Basically in the left sidebar if you click the heading they collapse. However when you do this you will notice the list of check boxes glitch about like there is a margin or padding being added somewhere.

I can't seem to find the problem or what is causing this anyone else see what's going?

**Issue**

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<h3 data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Colour"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i> Colour</h3>
<div id="Colour" class="filter-group collapse in">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox"> Red (221)</label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox"> Dry White (128)</label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox"> Sparkling (19)</label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox"> Sweet White (16)</label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox"> Rose (6)</label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox"> Mixed Cases (1)</label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox"> Spirits and Liqueurs (1)</label>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of `overflow: hidden` being added to the collapsing element and gets margins collapsed:

```css
.site-sidebar .filter-group {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Lemme know if the solution works. Waiting for you as I tried it in your website using Dev Tools and it worked. Also you might find that there's an increased space because of `margins` of `<ul>`.

The other solution is to get rid of the `margin`s of `<div class="checkbox">`:

```css
.site-sidebar .filter-group .checkbox {
  margin: 0;
}
```